# selenium using python: how to correctly click() an element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

while learning how to use selenium, Im trying to click an element but nothing happens and Im unable to reach the next page. this is the relevant page: http://buyme.co.il and Im trying to click: הרשמה

I managed to print the desired element (הרשמה) so I guess Im reaching the correct place in the page. but 'click()' doesnt work.
the second span `<span>הרשמה</span>` is what i want to click:

```html
<li data-ember-action="636">
        <a>
            <span class="seperator-link">כניסה</span>
            <span>הרשמה</span>
        </a>
 </li>
```

```py
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* [@id="ember591"]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a/span[2]'):
    print (elem.text)
    elem.click()
```

also tried this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember591"]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a').click()
```

I expected to get to the "lightbox" which contain the registration fields.
Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use the `pyautogui` module. You can find documentation [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: @ArnavPoddar that is an interesting idea, however im specifically trying to accomplish this task using selenium.

Comment: Ok, good luck on your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) - An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://buyme.co.il/")

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ember591')))

elm = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="ember591"]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a')

elm[0].click()
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'login')))

email = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@id='ember1005']/div[1]/label/input")
email[0].send_keys("abc@gmail.com")

password = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@id='ember1005']/div[2]/label/input")
password[0].send_keys("test1234567")

login = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@id="ember1005"]/button')
login[0].click()
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like that worked. however the browser closes imminently so I wasnt sure I reached the "lightbox". is there a way to keep it open?

Comment: @holder Always use `WebDriverWait` wait utils object is not available or if you don't know HTML elements then use `time` module.`import time`

Comment: `time.sleep(4)`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='הרשמה']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: looks like your method works as well. thanks. im not familiar with Ember.js or javascript so thanks for the info.  also, in your code you wrote: `expected_conditions as EC` is this necesary or can you use just `expected_conditions`?

Comment: @holder As per my import `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC` I have sweetened the long `expected_conditions` as **`EC`** for the ease of use.

Comment: nice! 
so moving further with this, Im trying to click other elements inside the "lightbox". not wanting to bother you people for every element, I need to understand the logic of this. I tried clicking on `להרשמה` using this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember572"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/p/span[text()=להרשמה]').click()`
whats wrong with this approach?

Comment: @holder Let's not stretch this discussion as you are having an accepted answer. Good luck 